# Existing Rdata file cannot be uploaded and found when app is deployed in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have the `shiny` app below which locally works fine so you do not need to check the code except from line 3. The issue is that when I deploy this app to `shinyapps.io` the app is not working and as a message from the logs I get:

```
cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Ant/foo_upwork.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
 Error in value[[3L]](cond) : cannot open the connection
```

Of course my file path is correct and the file exists. What is the problem? How can I read `.Rdata` file to `shinyapps.io`?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
load("C:/Users/User/Documents/Ant/foo_upwork.RData")
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Scattetrplot"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xcol", "X Variable",
                choices = c("Acled_Total", "Acled_no_inst", "Acled_Health"), selected = "Acled_Total",
                multiple = F
    ),
    selectInput("ycol", "Y Variable",
                choices = c("I3", "I4", "I5", "I6"), selected = "I3",
                multiple = F
    ),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  new <- reactive({
    myvars <- input$xcol
    newdata <- foo_upwork[myvars]
  })
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(foo_upwork, aes(x = .data[[input$xcol]], y = .data[[input$ycol]], fill = ADM0_FR, shape = ADM0_FR)) +
      geom_point(position = position_jitter(h = 0.1, w = 0.1), alpha = 0.5, size = 1.5) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "orange")) +
      scale_shape_manual(values = c(23, 24, 25)) +
      geom_text(
        position = position_jitter(h = 0.10, w = 0.55),
        aes(label = ifelse(new()[, 1] > quantile(new()[, 1], 0.98),
                           as.character(ADM3_FR), ""
        )), vjust = 3, size = 2.75
      ) +
      labs(x = as.character(input$xcol), y = as.character(input$ycol)) +
      theme_bw()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Obviously this path `"C:/Users/User/Documents/Ant/foo_upwork.RData"` doesn't exist on Shiny apps server, you need to use relative path.

Comment: I tried with this as well load("~/Ant/foo_upwork.RData")
still works only locally

Comment: As @RonakShah commented, you need to use the relative path since the shinyapps.io machine your app is running on is different from your local machine. [here](https://here.r-lib.org/) is a package with the goal to solve these issues.

Comment: here("Ant", "foo_upwork.RData") ??

Comment: how can I use it to my path above?

Comment: That entirely depends on your project structure and is difficult to answer with the info you provided. Reading the [Get Started vignette](https://here.r-lib.org/articles/here.html) should give you all the info you need though. I suggest you simply put  `message(here::here())` at the top of your server function. This will tell you the path of your working directory.